# Implementing Drag and Swapping items in windows Phone

Tags: winforms, windows-phone-7, windows-7, drag-and-drop

I am new to windows phone.My problem is the following:
I have a grid of items which are buttons. I want to implement drag and swap feature for the buttons.How  to do this in WP7 platform.

Comment: have you look at my blog post from early last year ? http://invokeit.wordpress.com/2012/02/10/wp7-drag-drop-example/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution! **xaml** looks like this

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
                <toolkit:WrapPanel Height="510" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,56,0,0" Name="wrapPanel1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="411">
                    <Button Content="1" Height="124" Name="button2" Width="134">
                        <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                            <toolkit:GestureListener DragDelta="GestureListener_DragDelta" DragStarted="GestureListener_DragStarted" DragCompleted="GestureListener_DragCompleted" />
                        </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                    </Button>
                    <Button Content="2" Height="124" Name="button3" Width="134" >
                        <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                            <toolkit:GestureListener DragDelta="GestureListener_DragDelta" DragStarted="GestureListener_DragStarted" DragCompleted="GestureListener_DragCompleted" />
                        </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                    </Button>
                    <Button Content="3" Height="124" Name="button4" Width="134">
                        <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                            <toolkit:GestureListener DragDelta="GestureListener_DragDelta" DragStarted="GestureListener_DragStarted" DragCompleted="GestureListener_DragCompleted" />
                        </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                    </Button>
                    <Button Content="4" Height="124" Name="button5"  Width="134">
                        <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                            <toolkit:GestureListener DragDelta="GestureListener_DragDelta" DragStarted="GestureListener_DragStarted" DragCompleted="GestureListener_DragCompleted" />
                        </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                    </Button>
                    <Button Content="5" Height="124" Name="button6"  Width="134">
                        <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                            <toolkit:GestureListener DragDelta="GestureListener_DragDelta" DragStarted="GestureListener_DragStarted" DragCompleted="GestureListener_DragCompleted" />
                        </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                    </Button>
                    <Button Content="6" Height="124" Name="button7"  Width="134">
                        <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                            <toolkit:GestureListener DragDelta="GestureListener_DragDelta" DragStarted="GestureListener_DragStarted" DragCompleted="GestureListener_DragCompleted" />
                        </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                    </Button>
                    <Button Content="7" Height="124" Name="button8"  Width="134">
                        <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                            <toolkit:GestureListener DragDelta="GestureListener_DragDelta" DragStarted="GestureListener_DragStarted" DragCompleted="GestureListener_DragCompleted" />
                        </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                    </Button>
                    <Button Content="8" Height="124" Name="button9"  Width="134">
                        <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                            <toolkit:GestureListener DragDelta="GestureListener_DragDelta" DragStarted="GestureListener_DragStarted" DragCompleted="GestureListener_DragCompleted" />
                        </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                    </Button>
                    <Button Content="9" Height="124" Name="button10"  Width="134">
                        <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                            <toolkit:GestureListener DragDelta="GestureListener_DragDelta" DragStarted="GestureListener_DragStarted" DragCompleted="GestureListener_DragCompleted" />
                        </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                    </Button>
                    <Button Content="10" Height="124" Name="button11" MouseLeftButtonDown="mouseDown" Width="134">
                        <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                            <toolkit:GestureListener DragDelta="GestureListener_DragDelta" DragStarted="GestureListener_DragStarted" DragCompleted="GestureListener_DragCompleted" />
                        </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                    </Button>
                    <Button Content="11" Height="124" Name="button12"  Width="134">
                        <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                            <toolkit:GestureListener DragDelta="GestureListener_DragDelta" DragStarted="GestureListener_DragStarted" DragCompleted="GestureListener_DragCompleted" />
                        </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                    </Button>
                    <Button Content="12" Height="124" Name="button13" Width="134">
                        <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                            <toolkit:GestureListener DragDelta="GestureListener_DragDelta" DragStarted="GestureListener_DragStarted" DragCompleted="GestureListener_DragCompleted" />
                        </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                    </Button>
                </toolkit:WrapPanel>
            </Grid>
```

Now the code behind C#

TranslateTransform translateTransform;

PointCollection points = new System.Windows.Media.PointCollection();

Button firstObject;

```
 private void GestureListener_DragStarted(object sender, DragStartedGestureEventArgs e)
     {
             translateTransform = new TranslateTransform();
             firstObject = sender as Button;
             var transform1 = firstObject.TransformToVisual(wrapPanel1);
            Point absolutePosition1 = transform1.Transform(new Point(0, 0));                 
     }







private void GestureListener_DragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaGestureEventArgs e)
      {
          var moveablebutton = sender as Button;
          moveablebutton.RenderTransform = translateTransform;
           translateTransform.X += e.HorizontalChange;
           translateTransform.Y += e.VerticalChange;          
      }





 private void GestureListener_DragCompleted(object sender, DragCompletedGestureEventArgs e)
   {
                var lastObject = sender as Button;
                Button b=new Button();
                int count = wrapPanel1.Children.Count;
                int index = wrapPanel1.Children.IndexOf(lastObject);
                var transform2 = lastObject.TransformToVisual(wrapPanel1);
                Point absolutePositon2 = transform2.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
                Point P1;
                Point P2 ;
                Point P3 ;
                Point P4 ;
                P1 = e.GetPosition(wrapPanel1);
                P2 = new Point(P1.X+134, P1.Y+124);



                Button swapitem=null;

                foreach (UIElement ctrl in wrapPanel1.Children)
                {
                    int index2;
                    var transform3 = ctrl.TransformToVisual(wrapPanel1);
                    Point comparePos = transform3.Transform(new Point(0, 0));

                    swapitem = ctrl as Button;
                    index2 = wrapPanel1.Children.IndexOf(swapitem);
                    if (index != index2)
                    {
                        P3 = new Point(comparePos.X, comparePos.Y);
                        P4 = new Point(comparePos.X + 158, comparePos.Y+170);
                       if (!(P2.Y < P3.Y || P1.Y > P4.Y || P2.X < P3.X || P1.X > P4.X))
                        {
                            swapitem = ctrl as Button;
                            index2 = wrapPanel1.Children.IndexOf(swapitem);
                            b = lastObject as Button;
                            b.RenderTransform = translateTransform;
                            translateTransform.X -= e.HorizontalChange;
                            translateTransform.Y -= e.VerticalChange;
                            wrapPanel1.Children.Remove(lastObject);
                            wrapPanel1.Children.Remove(swapitem);
                            // wrapPanel1.Children.RemoveAt(index2);
                            if (index < index2)
                            {
                                wrapPanel1.Children.Insert(index, swapitem);
                                wrapPanel1.Children.Insert(index2, b);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                wrapPanel1.Children.Insert(index2, b);
                                wrapPanel1.Children.Insert(index, swapitem);
                            }
                            break;
                        }}

                }

            }
```

Comment: @Shilpa, can you add some comments to this code? Because it needs them. Names P1, P2, P3, p4 don't tell, what exactly each of these points is used for. And also constant values (158, 170), where are they taken from?

Comment: @Olter the constant values added are the width and height of the button. P1,P2 are the upper left corner and lower right corner of button1 respectively.so is p3,p4 for the second button to be compared.

Comment: Well, how about renaming them? `MovedButtonBottomRightPoint = new Point(MovedButtonTopLeftPoint.X + lastObject.ActualWidth, MovedButtonTopLeftPoint.Y + lastObject.ActualHeight);` looks more clear than  `P2 = new Point(P1.X+134, P1.Y+124);`. Anyway, thanks for the answer.